# Looking for good alternate to salt pills during exercise

Tags: exercise

I have done some fairly long events (Ironman several times and all the training it takes to get there) and I have found that hyponatremia is a key issue for me.

I am always interested in easy to handle ways to get salt in during exercise.

I pretty much just carry salt packets with me, and eat one per hour, and have found that works pretty well, but have been wondering if there are better alternates.

Oh and just to be difficult, whatever it is, needs to be kosher.

Comment: salt packets, like sugar packets, but salt?

Comment: @Ryan Miller: Yep.  Like you get at a restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

There are several commercial products available.

Probably the most common are Endurolytes from Hammer Nutrition.
You could also check out SaltStick.com.
And for a "it's in there" approach to fueling, INFINIT Nutrition has custom blends.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Succeed! S-Caps](http://www.succeedscaps.com/main_scaps_notice.html) and have used Hammer Endurolytes. Both work well because they are a gel capsule and they have more than just sodium. You need potassium as well as calcium and magnesium in much smaller amounts.

The difference is that S-Caps has much more in it. You need to decide if you want to talk multiple Endurolytes or one S-Cap. Flexibility vs convenience.

Lastly, make sure you take these with lots of water. They are concentrated enough that if they don't dissolve then you have a highly concentrated bolus in your stomach which may cause you to vomit.

Comment: Will have to look into these.  My issue is it needs to be kosher as well, which I updated the original question to reflect.

Comment: I took a look at both the Succeed! and Hammer websites. Succeed makes no mention of kosher. Hammer lists their [kosher products](http://www.hammernutrition.com/knowledge/are-hammer-nutrition-products-kosher.15204.html) but Endurolytes is not listed. I did some quick research on kosher in this respect - you'll have to decide how your religion applies but salt tabs are minerals and not animal derived so I'm not sure it's relevant.